# How to build time series transformer?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, time-series, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have a machine learning project for a college assignment. but I don't really understand with the model that I want to make.
I want to make time series transformer to predict/classification using bearing fault dataset.
if you have related literature, reference video, or maybe you master transformer time series, please help me.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from datasets import load_dataset
```

```
# Define the tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
model_name = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
```

```
# Load the CWRU bearing fault dataset
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='fault_48_load_0.csv', split='train')
```

```
# Define a mapping from labels to integers
label_map = {'Normal': 0, 'Ball': 1, 'InnerRace': 2, 'OuterRace': 3}
```

```
# Define a PyTorch dataset
class BearingFaultDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset, label_map, tokenizer, max_length):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.label_map = label_map
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = self.dataset[idx]
        label = self.label_map[item['fault']]
        signal = np.array(item['signal'])
        inputs = self.tokenizer(signal.tolist(), padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=self.max_length, return_tensors='pt')
        inputs = {k: v.squeeze(0) for k, v in inputs.items()}
        inputs['labels'] = torch.tensor(label)
        return inputs

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)
```

```
# Create training and testing datasets
train_dataset = BearingFaultDataset(dataset['DE_data'], label_map, tokenizer, max_length=300)
test_dataset = BearingFaultDataset(dataset['DE_data'], label_map, tokenizer, max_length=300)
```

```
# Create training and testing data loaders
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=16)
```

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

# Define the transformer model
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=len(label_map))
```

```
# Define the optimizer and loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

```
# Train the model
for epoch in range(5):
    model.train()
    for batch in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].cuda()
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].cuda()
        labels = batch['labels'].cuda()
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        total_loss = 0
        total_correct = 0
        total_samples = 0
        for batch in test_loader:
            input_ids = batch['input_ids'].cuda()
            attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].cuda()
            labels = batch['labels'].cuda()
            outputs
```

but I got error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 4
      2 for epoch in range(5):
      3     model.train()
----> 4     for batch in train_loader:
      5         optimizer.zero_grad()
      6         input_ids = batch['input_ids'].cuda()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:628, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    625 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    626     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    627     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 628 data = self._next_data()
    629 self._num_yielded += 1
    630 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    631         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    632         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:671, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    669 def _next_data(self):
    670     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 671     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    672     if self._pin_memory:
    673         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py:58, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     56         data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     57     else:
---> 58         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     59 else:
     60     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py:58, in <listcomp>(.0)
     56         data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     57     else:
---> 58         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     59 else:
     60     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

Cell In [6], line 11, in BearingFaultDataset.__getitem__(self, idx)
      9 def __getitem__(self, idx):
     10     item = self.dataset[idx]
---> 11     label = self.label_map[item['fault']]
     12     signal = np.array(item['signal'])
     13     inputs = self.tokenizer(signal.tolist(), padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=self.max_length, return_tensors='pt')

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```